# quotient space, Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X = [-1,1] \times \{0, 1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with the induced topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $X$ is a Hausdorff space as a subspace of a Hausdorff space.

The question is now, if

$Y = X \setminus_{\sim}$ with $\sim$ induced by $(t,0) \sim (t,1)$
$\forall t \in [-1,- 1/2] \cup [1/2, 1]$ is also Hausdorff ?

I think yes, but I do not see how to prove this statement.

Comment: Can you visualize what this space should look like? Say, embedded in some $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I think about the lines $[-1, -1/2] \cup [1/2, 1]$ and $(- 1/2, 1/2) \times \{ 0, 1 \}$.

Comment: Note that the resulting space is connected.

Comment: Okay, I do not see how this will help to show the statement ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $p,q\in X/\sim$ with $p\neq q$, and $\pi: X \to X/\sim$ the canonical map. Observe that $(X/\sim)\setminus \{ [(-1/2,0)],[1/2,0] \}$ can be cover with the disjoint open sets of $X/\sim$:

- $X_1 = \{ [(x,y)] \in X/\sim : x \in [-1,-1/2) \}$
- $X_2 = \{ [(x,y)] \in X/\sim : (x,y) \in (-1/2,1/2)\times\{0,1 \} \}$
- $X_3 = \{ [(x,y)] \in X/\sim : x \in (1/2,1] \}$

Each $X_i$ is Hausdorff because $\pi^{-1}(X_i)$ is open and Hausdorff, and $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is finite for each $p\in X_i$. So we only need to prove the Hausdorff property for  $[(-1/2,0)]$ with respect to al $X/\sim$ and the same for $[1/2,0]$. This easy again because the preimage by $\pi$ of these points are finite.